# real-time socket.io client web browser

Tags: html, socket.io, real-time

I'm trying to create a simple local web-server that collects real time data from a remote server. The remote server is not under my control and it streams out text lines continuosly.

I think scocket.io is Ok for that purpose but I'm really new to node.js and I don't know where is the problem. I've installed socket.io with:

npm install socket.io

then I wrote a simple index.html page deployed in my www dir:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        var socket = io.connect('http://192.168.1.100:8888');
        socket.on('data', function(msg) {
            var val = msg;
             $('#data_value').html(val);
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Data Stream</h1>
        lines: <span id="data_value"></span><br/>
</body>
</html>
```

When I load index.html with the browser I can see the web page with the correct title and the the string "lines:" but no data is printed out.

If I try to directly browse the remote server at http://92.168.1.100:8888 I can see the stream.

Can you help me?

Comment: "If I try to directly browse the remote server at http://92.168.1.100:8888 I can see the stream."
You can see the steam as what? HTML, XML, JSON string? If you can see it on the browser I don't think that is the port for websocket server?

Comment: Well, I put the http://192.168.1.100:8888 on my browser and I can see the strings coming down. I think they are html but the important thing is that they appear as expect. As a second test I'm able to collect them using socat as:    socat tcp:192.168.1.100:8888 -

Answer (score 0):

92.168.1.*, is the home ip address for routers. You say that the server isn't under your control but it's still being run from the same router your client is trying to connect to.

So you're listening for a call from a server, on port 8888 but this server is a local one. If someone else is running this server you're going to need to ask them to portforward it and send them their public ip address, otherwise your website is just waiting for your PC to be hosting this server and send you the data :(

Comment: Sorry I've made a mistake the address is 192.168.1.100 and currently my machine is under the same local subnet (my IP is 192.168.1.99) and all the things I'm doing are inside the subnet 192.168.1.

Comment: Is it possible to see the server code? I can't see any issue with this. I'd suggest putting the script tag below the body tag

Comment: As I told you I don't have access to the server. The stream is generated by a already compiled code. I'll try to move the script tag as you suggest.

Comment: Ok, scrip tag moved. Unfortunately no changes... sigh

Comment: If the server ins't written using socket.io I think you're going to have trouble getting this data. Because the clien't is listening to a Socket.io broadcast called 'data'

Comment: Ok I think you've fond out the problem. Is it a way to recover the stream without using the socket.io

Answer (score 0):

I think you have misunderstood how socket.io works.
The problem seems to be in `socket.on` part of your code. Socket.io only responds to socket.io broadcast events not a stream of strings that is being updated by a server.

Is 192.168.1.100 server a socket.io server? If not then your web app will not work as a socket.io client.